# Why do I need 20 reputation to chat even in the feedback channel?

Tags: discussion, chat

I'm not sure how to answer to a previous answer so I joined the chat and I couldn't ask anyone as I'm lacking repuatation.

Come on guys, this side is supposed to be "easy" and enable an instant interaction -isn't it?

Comment: This belongs to META (http://meta.askubuntu.com) because it's not about Ubuntu but askubuntu

Comment: Belongs to meta, but it seems the user can't post there until it gets 20 reputation.

Comment: Why would you want to give _chat_ feedback if you can't even chat in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

This site's number one focus is providing Quality Answers and Questions. The reputation is modeled around that - for both Chat and on the site. Gaining 20 reputation is *relatively* easy so long as you participate within the site (If you gain two up votes on either a question you have authored *or* an answer - as an example). The Chat is considered a *Third Place* on the StackExchange network and isn't the main focus of the site as a whole.

I believe it's meant to deter new users from jumping into chat and asking questions without first understanding or participating on the main site.

Comment: Same again (see Marco's response to my last question, about user restrictions), it's fair, even if it is frustrating initially.

Answer (score 3):

It probably prevents people from being able to spam the site with bots because you actually have to do something non trivial on here before you get the rep

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but getting that reputation is pretty easy. Just explore the site a little bit, vote on some questions and answers you like or register on other Stack Exchange sites and you will get them.

Comment: AFAIK registering on other sites only helps when you have 200+ rep?

Answer (score 1):

Would you have used the site enough for feedback before getting a meager 20 rep?